# Pull Screen not indicator with Swipe Refresh Layout Android

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I am implementing swipe refresh layout to my fragment. It works perfectly, but I want to pull the screen as animation not the indicator itself. I also want not to show the default indicator because I have my own custom progress bar.

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: post your code here

Answer (score 0):

use this to hide the progress indicator

```
if (swipeLayout.isRefreshing()) {
   swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

and for animating the activity, you can use transitions in android. Follow this [link](https://medium.com/@andkulikov/animate-all-the-things-transitions-in-android-914af5477d50) to get some cool transitions and just implement it to the root element of your activity.